# Cassandra- Getting No converter found capable of converting from type [com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate] to type [java.util.Date]

Tags: spring-data-jpa, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I'm building a demo app , using springboot, spring data JPA and Cassandra 3.0. Tried below option but getting error saying ***Date is deprecated as of JDK 1.1***

private Date date = new Date(ld.getMillisSinceEpoch());

**Entity:**

```
Table("appointment")
public class Appointment {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private Date date;
    private int doctorId;
    private int patientId;
```

***Code which tries to get data and fails***

```
public List<Appointment> getPatientByPhone(long phone){
        List<Appointment> appnts= new ArrayList<Appointment>();
        try {
            Patient patient= patientRepo.findByPhone(phone);
            if(patient != null) {
                List<Appointment> appoints= appointRepo.findByPatientId(patient.getId());
                for(ListIterator<Appointment> appoint=appoints.listIterator();appoint.hasNext();) {
                    appnts.add(appoint.next());

                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            logger.info("Error occured while fetching from DB");
        }
        return appnts;
    }
```

***Controller***

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="/patient/phone/{phone}",produces = "application/json")
    public List<Appointment> getDoctorById(@PathVariable long phone)
    {
        return patientService.getPatientByPhone(phone);
    }
```

In Database, date column is of type 'DATE'.
Please help.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? In what line of your code does it happen? Is it a compile time or run time error? If the latter please include the full stack trace.

Comment: @JensSchauder when i run in DEBUG mode and access through my GUI, it fails there (i get null response), see above code snippet, pasting exact line below:
try
    }
   }
  }**catch(Exception e) {
   logger.info("Error occured while fetching from DB");**
  }
  return appnts;
 }
 when i see the value of variable 'e'- No converter found capable of converting from type [com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate] to type [java.util.Date]

Comment: Oh, I missed that. You are throwing away the errror. change `log.info(String)` into `log.error(String, Throwable)`

Comment: Next step would be to write an integration test to reproduce the problem.